# Unable to update PySimpleGUI progress bar in multithreaded python program

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, pysimplegui, concurrent.futures

I wrote a multi-threaded python program that downloads files from an API service that uses asyncio and concurrent.futures. In main.py I draw the UI and call a function called get_json in file_managment.py which calls another function called create_shape_file in file_utilities.py. When the shape files are being processed I have a counter variable that is incremented as files are done processing. I keep trying to update the progress bar with the value of the counter variable however it doesn't seem to be doing anything to the progress bar in main. How can I properly increment the progress bar? I'm not that familiar with multi-threading in python.

Relevant code snippet from main.py:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import grower_list
import WithLeaf_api
import file_managment
from asyncio import as_completed, futures
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
import concurrent.futures
import sys

def main():
    #sg.theme('Default')   # Add a touch of color
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Save location for files'), sg.FolderBrowse(initial_folder='C:/WithLeafFiles/')],

                [sg.Input(key='-start_date-', size=(20,1)), sg.CalendarButton('Choose start date', title='Pick a date', no_titlebar=False, close_when_date_chosen=False, format='%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00',  target='-start_date-', month_names=('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'))],
                [sg.Input(key='-end_date-', size=(20,1)), sg.CalendarButton('Choose end date', title='Pick a date', no_titlebar=False, close_when_date_chosen=False, format='%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59',  target='-end_date-', month_names=('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'))],

                [sg.Button('Select growers to pull', key='open')],
                [sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='horizontal', size=(20,20), key='-progbar1-')],
                [sg.Button('Get planted shape files', key='run')],
                [sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='horizontal', size=(20,20), key='-progbar2-')]]
    
    # Create the Window
    window = sg.Window('WithLeaf Pull', layout)
    # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
            break
        if values['-end_date-']<values['-start_date-']:#force closes the program if user enters dates incorrectly
            sys.exit()
        #print('You entered ', values[0])
        print(values)
        if event == 'open':
            window['-progbar1-'].update(25)
            leaf_id=pop_leaf_id(values['-start_date-'], values['-end_date-'])
            window['-progbar1-'].update(50)
            print('Leaf IDs have been populated\n')
            grower_names=pop_names(leaf_id)
            window['-progbar1-'].update(75)
            picked_ID=grower_list.GrowerList(grower_names, leaf_id)
            window['-progbar1-'].update(100)
        if event == "run":
            print('processing the files...')
            file_managment.get_json(picked_ID, values['-start_date-'], values['-end_date-'], values['Browse'])
            window.close()
            

    
    window.close()

main()
```

Relevant code snippet from file_managment.py:

```
from pickle import NONE
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import os
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import WithLeaf_api
import file_utilities
import grower_list
import gc
from asyncio import as_completed, futures
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
import concurrent.futures
import urllib
import sqlalchemy

def get_json(selected_leaf_id, start_time, end_time, save_location):
    counter=0
    save_location = save_location + '/'
    print(f'selected leaf ids are {selected_leaf_id}')
    print('getting the sugar planting operations in the selected time range')
    operation_response = WithLeaf_api.get_all_operations_by_start_date(start_time, end_time)
    total_operations = int(operation_response.headers['X-Total-Count'])

    current_page = 0
    valid_sugarbeet_operations = []

    while total_operations > 0:
        current_operation_request = WithLeaf_api.get_all_operations_by_start_date(start_time, end_time, current_page)
        current_operation_request_json = current_operation_request.json()
        #this causes 'main thread is not in main loop' error from the gui framework
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
            for item in range(len(selected_leaf_id)):
                operation_results = executer.map(process_operation, current_operation_request_json["operations"], selected_leaf_id[item])
                
        for result in operation_results:
            if result is not None:
                valid_sugarbeet_operations.append(result)
        
        total_operations -= 100
        current_page += 1

    file_utilities.save_location = save_location
    
    #increase the progress bar value here in the thread

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
        future_list = { executer.submit(file_utilities.create_shape_file, op) : op for op in valid_sugarbeet_operations }
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_list):
            data = future.result()
            counter=counter+10
            print(f'the counter is currently {counter}')
            main.window['-progbar2-'].update(counter)#doesn't do anything to the progress bar
            #return counter
```

Comment: There's a Demo Program named `Demo_Multithreaded_ProgressBar.py` that shows you one method.  There's an eCookbook example that also demonstrates how - https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/multi-threaded/multi-threaded-download-2022-design-pattern